# IPTables: Block incoming traffic connection to your IP address of your virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, iptables, firewall

Host OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Guest OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (Virtual Box)

I want to block incoming traffic connection from Virtual machine with IPTables. I have searched, One solution I found is static IP for Virtual Machine on bridge interface. But It is not the solution for me. I am wondering if there is any way to block virtual machine traffic both with NAT and Bridge Interface (without static IP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative would be to block traffic using MAC address filtering. So, you would basically need to get the MAC address of the network interface you want to block, and then use an iptables rule such as the following:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source 1E:2B:65:48:54:AD -j REJECT
```

The above rule will block all incoming traffic from the specified MAC address. If you simply wanted to block traffic to a specific port, you could do something like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m mac --mac-source 1E:2B:65:48:54:AD -j REJECT
```